# Fully clickable NSComboBox?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface, nscombobox

In the Cocoa UI controls we have the `NSComboBox` and I'm wondering if it can be set to act like the 'combo boxes' that Apple uses in the OSX System Preferences. These are fully clickable (instead of only the right-most arrow part) and they also look and act slightly different (e.g they extend to bottom AND top).

Can the `NSComboBox` changed to act like this or is this a different control altogether that Apple is using there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually looking for an `NSPopUpButton`, which is different from an `NSComboBox`.

[image: NSPopUpButton vs NSComboBox]

Comment: Thanks! That's the one!